# Is $\mathbb{R}[X]/(P)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ for every irreducible polynomial $P$ of degree $2?$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, complex-numbers

Trying to solve a problem, I got stuck on the following question.

> If $P\in\mathbb R[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial and $\operatorname {deg} P=2$, then is it true that $$\mathbb{R}[X]/(P)\cong\mathbb C?$$

I believe it must be true from the bits I've been hearing throughout my studies, but of which I haven't seen proofs. I've been unable to find anything on the internet other than [this single page](https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093894626). It tells me that there is something called Weierstrass' theorem which should be relevant, but can't find even the precise statement of the theorem, let alone the proof.

Here's what I have tried.

First of all, I can assume that $P$ is monic, because for any polynomial of degree $2$ there's a monic polynomial generating the same ideal in $\mathbb R[X].$ So I have

$$P(x)=x^2+bx+c$$

for some real numbers $b,c$ such that $b^2<4c$.

I want to assume there is an isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R[X]/(P)\to\mathbb C$ and work out what it should look like. I will denote by $[S]$ the coset of $S\in \mathbb R[X]$ in $\mathbb R[X]/(P).$ I'd like to find $S$ such that $\phi([S])=i.$

I have

$$
[x^2+bx+c-1]\mapsto -1,
$$

So the coset that is mapped to $-1$ has to be a square root of $[x^2+bx+c-1]$ in $\mathbb R[X]/(P).$ Such a coset must be represented by a linear polynomial $kx+l$. Thus
$$(kx+l)^2-(x^2+bx+c-1)\in (P),$$

that is
$$
(kx+l)^2-(x^2+bx+c-1)\equiv a(x^2+bx+c)
$$

for some real number $a$, and further

$$
(k^2-1-a)x^2+(2kl-b-ab)x+l^2-c-ac+1\equiv 0.
$$

This gives

$$
\begin{cases}
k^2=1+a\\
l^2=(1+a)c+1\\
2kl=(1+a)b
\end{cases}
$$

The problem is that solving this gives formulas that are very difficult to handle. And I need to handle them if I want to prove that what I'm constructing is indeed an isomorphism. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Dear ymar: Are you supposed to know the fact that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I do know this fact from my course in analytic complex functions. It was proven there.

Comment: The non-constructive proof is simple then: $\mathbb{C}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(P)$, and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(P)$ is an extension of $\mathbb{R}$. Now, look at the degrees of the extensions (i.e. their dimension as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces).

Comment: Dear ymar: Then you know that any proper algebraic extension of $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I think I understand. If $\xi\in \mathbb C$ is a root of $P$, then $\mathbb R[X]/(P)\cong \mathbb R[\xi].$ I have $\mathbb R\subseteq\mathbb R[\xi]\subseteq\mathbb C,$ and since $\operatorname{deg}(P)=2$, it must be that $(\mathbb R[\xi]:\mathbb R)=2$. But also $(\mathbb C:\mathbb R)=2$, so $(\mathbb C:\mathbb R[\xi])=1.$ So I get $\mathbb C=\mathbb R[\xi]\cong \mathbb R[X]/(P).$ But I don't see where I used the fact that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @Hurkyl OH, I see! :) $\xi$ is in $\mathbb C$ _because_ of the closedness.

Comment: Right. Well, technically, the $\xi$ I mentioned in my answer is not in $\mathbb{C}$. But because $\mathbb{R}[\xi]$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$, it must be (isomorphic to) a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, the algebraic closure. (more precisely, isomorphic to a sub-extension of the extension $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$). (and, of course, this isomorphism sends $\xi$ to something that really is in $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: @Hurkyl I should have used a different symbol. I didn't mean $\xi$ to be the same as in your answer, but simply a root of this polynomial in $\mathbb C$. I know that when $F\subseteq K$ are fields and $k\in K,$ then if $T\in F[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $k$, we have $F[k]\cong F[X]/(T)$. I'm using this fact. Is it more than right-ish now?

Comment: Yah, that sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ For an *explicit* isomorphism proceed as in the quadratic formula. Suppose R is an ordered field which is closed under taking sqrts of positive elements, and suppose that some polynomial $\rm\ a\:X^2 + b\:X + c \in R[X]\: $ of negative discriminant $\rm\:d = b^2 - 4ac < 0\:$  has a root $\rm\:x\:$ in some extension field $\rm\:F\supset R\:.$ Then $\rm\:-1\:$ is a square in $\rm\:F\:$ since
$$\rm  (b+2ax)^2 =\: b^2+4a(bx+ax^2) =\: b^2+4a(-c) =\: d < 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \left(\frac{b+2ax}{\sqrt{-d}}\right)^2 =\: -1 $$

Answer (score 2):

You're making working with the quotient ring harder than it needs to be. You're familiar with working with the usual presentation of the complex numbers $\mathbb{R}[i] / (i^2 + 1)$, right? Working in $\mathbb{R}[x] / (P)$ isn't much different; it's just $x^2$ reduces to something else.

It might help you to define a new variable $\xi$ to be the image of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}[x] / (P)$, and do arithmetic in terms of $\xi$.

Anyways, it's much, much easier to figure out the image $x$ in $\mathbb{C}$ than it is to find a preimage of $i$ in $\mathbb{R}[x] / (P)$. (the latter shouldn't be all *that* hard once you get used to arithmetic, though)

Hint: for it to be a homomorphism, you need to find a complex number α such that $\alpha^2 + b \alpha + c = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb R[X]/(P)$ injects into $\mathbb C$ (and the injection preserves $\mathbb R$), then $X$ must map to one of the complex roots of $P$ which you can find using the quadratic formula.

So if $p+qi$ is a root of $P$, then the residue class $[\frac{1}{q}X-\frac{p}{q}]$ ought to behave like $i$. Proving that is probably just a matter of inserting the quadratic formula (which splits nicely into real and imaginary terms here) and reducing.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to complete this constructive proof and if I have trouble, I'll ask here again.